# How can I select a distinct combination of values across 3 or 4 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct, denormalization

I inherited a non-normalized table in SQL Server, with 15 columns of purchase records.

> | Index |TransNo| Fund | Cost | City | Zip | Bank | Risk_YesNo |......
>
> | 1|           1| Green| 34| NYC | Zip | Sunt |
>
> | 2|    12| Party| 345.23| NYC | Zip | BOA_BS |
>
> | 3| 32| Edu | 43| Boston | Zip | BOA_BS |
>
> | 4| 53| Books| 56| Atl | Zip | citi |
>
> | 5| 422| Groc| 12315| Atl | Zip | Pink |

1. **I only need to extract 3 Distinct Combination of columns, and ignore the others like index and trans No and insert them into the
   same table (with the rest of columns as nulls**
2. In planning for next phase, I want to 2 Normalize - I also need to
       insert each distinct value into its own table

> | Fund | City | Bank |
>
> | Green | NYC | Sunt |  // all distinct combinations of green with city and bank
>
> | Green | NYC | BOA_BS |
>
> | Edu | NYC | Sunt |  // all distinct combinations of Edu with city and bank
>
> | Edu | NYC | BOA_BS |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert into .. select from` construct with `distinct` to get only distinct records like below

```
insert into mytable
select distinct Fund, City, Bank, null,null,null,....,null
from mytable
```

**EDIT:**

Per your comment below

> 1) how can I fill a default value for a column Risk_YesNo=Y

Just include that in the `SELECT` query [See example below]

> 2) how can I fill a random cost value for e.g. for a column [Cost]

You can include this as well in the `SELECT` part of query. If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above you can use [RAND()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177610.aspx) function to achieve the same.

`RAND()` function returns a `float` type result. So, in case your `Cost` column if of type `Integer`, you will have to cast it explicitly saying `CAST(RAND() as int)` [See example below]

With that your query will become

```
insert into mytable(Fund, City, Bank, Risk_YesNo, Cost, ....)
select distinct Fund, City, Bank, 'Y', RAND(), null,null,null,....,null
from mytable
```

Comment: **1) how can I fill a default value for a column Risk_YesNo=Y** 2) how can I fill a random cost value for e.g. for a column [Cost]

Comment: @aggie, See edit in answer. In future, make sure to post all your question clearly and concisely at once.